# GridView doesn't show

Tags: c#

Working on a basic C# web app here and I can't seem to get the GridView to show. I can see that its passing the code through because it changes my image from one to another but for some reason the Gridview doesn't show up. Using the button for the postback and my dropdown box has the variable for my stored procedure. I'm new to C# web apps (Vb Win app guy here) so I need a little guidance please.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is where my postback begins...
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string Quote = null;

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = null;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand = null;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader myReader = null;

            // Validate the SP
            Page.Validate();
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                Quote = DropDownList1.Text.ToString();

                try
                {
                    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data1"].ConnectionString;
                    myDatabaseConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
                    myCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

                    //Set up to use my stored procedure:
                    myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    myCommand.Connection = myDatabaseConnection;
                    myCommand.CommandText = "EditDataPage";
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuoteNumber", Quote);


                    //Use an SqlDataReader to execute the stored procedure and
                    //get the results into the GridView:
                    myDatabaseConnection.Open();
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    GridView1.DataSource = myReader;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    myDatabaseConnection.Close();
                    myDatabaseConnection.Dispose();
                    GridView1.Visible = true;
                    Image1.Visible = false;
                    Image2.Visible = true;
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException exception)
                {
                    ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
                    //Do cleanup tasks here:
                }
                finally
                {
                    myCommand = null;

                    if ((myReader != null) && !myReader.IsClosed)
                    {
                        myReader.Close();
                    }

                    myReader = null;

                    if ((myDatabaseConnection != null) && myDatabaseConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        myDatabaseConnection.Close();
                        myDatabaseConnection.Dispose();
                    }

                    myDatabaseConnection = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

Heres my aspx code:

#### Edit Data

Use the controls to move within the dataset, then edit and save what you need 
    for your reports.

```
<table class="yui-d0f">
    </table>
<table class="yui-main">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Data1 %>" 
                SelectCommand="EditDataPage" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:FormParameter FormField="DropDownList1" Name="QuoteNumber" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <table class="style1">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DropDownList" 
                            DataTextField="QuoteNumber" DataValueField="QuoteNumber" Height="23px" 
                            Width="188px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DropDownList" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Data1 %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT QuoteNumber FROM SF1411 GROUP BY QuoteNumber">
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table class="style1">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="style2">
            <asp:Button ID="ListAllButton" runat="server" Height="32px" Text="Show Data" 
                Width="111px" PostBackUrl="~/EditData.aspx" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                                        ImageUrl="~/_assets/img/lock-disabled-icon.png" />
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/_assets/img/lock-icon.png" 
                                        Visible="False" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:Label ID="ErrorLabel" runat="server" Font-Underline="True" 
                ForeColor="Maroon" Text="Error in Processing, try again later." Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="styled" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The portion of the aspx page with the gridview would be helpful

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanels? Can you post some code from the aspx page? Are you certain that your procedure actually returns any rows?

Comment: Have you got an empty data template on your GridView (that might not be the exact name)? Putting a small message in here will let you know if no results are being returned.

Comment: OK I added some of my aspx code guys, thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't seem to find your GridView in the markup you posted..

Comment: OK sorry it cut it off at the bottom. Its there now.

Comment: @Graham, yes I have a Error message is nothing pops up in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but the fact that you've got `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` on your GridView yet no columns defined looks a bit suspicious. I guess as a quick test you could change this attribute to `true` and see what happens.

If you do indeed want to specify the columns yourself (which in my experience is the norm), then you need to specify them, like this for example:

```
<asp:GridView ...>
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Surname") %>' runat="server" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks so much, yes that appeared to be the issue! I changed it to True and it works now!